# Make numbers in table of contents go to right of page in Pages

Tags: pages

When I insert a table of contents in Pages, the page numbers are inserted with only a tab character separating them from the title of the paragraph style. I would like the page numbers to go to the right of the screen, preferably with some sort of separation line between the two (e.g. dots). I am doing this to emulate the look of any standard table of contents:

[image: Standard table of contents]

Is this possible on Pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Show the ruler** (**View** → **Show Rulers**), then adjust the TOC as you desire, such as:

**Move the page numbers** by selecting all TOC levels (hold ⌘ while clicking to select multiple levels) and moving the marker on the ruler.

[image: Move page numbers]

**Indent headings** based on hierarchy by selecting sub levels and moving the marker on the ruler.

[image: Indent headings]

**Add dots between heading and page number** using the inspector: Text → Tabs: Leader.

[image: Leader dots]